# ElementAPI - Can I use javascript/ajax to load json

Tags: plugin-elementapi, ajax, json

Probably a dumb question, but since i wasn't sure while reading on github, i'll ask here.

I am wondering if I can reach the JSON I created with an URL or is it only for use in PHP?

I would like to load entries from craft from a json with ajax when i click on a button and i wasn't sure if it was possible with this plugin since there is no exemple.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Totally do-able.

Once you have the [ElementAPI](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) plugin downloaded and installed, you'll want to make sure you have created a file called `elementapi.php` and it is in your `/craft/config/` directory.

For simplicity's sake, I've used a stripped down version of the example on the github page.

**elementapi.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'news.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
            'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("news/{$entry->id}.json")
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Going back to your `/craft/config/` directory, you will want to enable [CSRF protection.](https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection).

Finally, (again for simplicity) here is an example of getting my news entries via ajax on docReay

**_layout.html**

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var data = {
            'CSRF': $('input[name="CSRF"]').val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            'type': 'get',
            'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'cache': false,
            'data': data,
            'url': 'news.json',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'timeout': 50000
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (error) {
                // Total fail.
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
...
```

Then if you look at your console, you should see something like this:

```
{"data":[{"title":"We just installed Craft!","url":"http:\/\/craftsandbox.dev\/news\/2016\/we-just-installed-craft","jsonUrl":"http:\/\/craftsandbox.dev\/news\/3.json"}],"meta":{"pagination":{"total":1,"count":1,"per_page":100,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1,"links":[]}}}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You better use GET rather than POST :

```
$(function () {
    var data = {
        'CSRF': $('input[name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN"]').val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        'type': 'get',
        'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'cache': false,
        'data': data,
        'url': 'news.json',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'timeout': 50000
    }).done(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    }).fail(function (error) {
       console.log('totalfail')
    });
});
```