# How do I get started with Element API plugin?

Tags: ajax, plugin-elementapi

I'd like to use the [Element API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) plugin.
I've follow the instructions mentioned here: [ElementAPI - Can I use javascript/ajax to load json](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15015/elementapi-can-i-use-javascript-ajax-to-load-json)

Here is my config/elementapi.php file :

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'news.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
            'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("news/{$entry->id}.json"),
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

and here my ajax request:

```
    $(function () {
        var data = {
            'CSRF': $('input[name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN"]').val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            'type': 'post',
            'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'cache': false,
            'data': data,
            'url': 'news.json',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'timeout': 50000
        }).done(function (response) {
           console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (error) {
                console.log('totalfail')
            });
        });
```

But it always returns a 400 error (as the JSON file looks like it doesn't exist).

What have I missed? Could someone provide a working example?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled ElementAPI plugin in the settings/plugin admin ui?

Comment: Yes I did. Also I'm running craft locally with Mamp. Don't know if that could cause any trouble...

Comment: Another dev is using Mamp and it runs fine.

Comment: I've just realized that I'm able to reach the json file by entering its url in the browser. My ajax function still returns a 400 error though...

Comment: Servers see Ajax requests almost identically to "regular" HTTP requests (they just come with 1 extra header) so I doubt it’s something server-side. Double-check that you're pointing the Ajax request to the right URL.

Comment: It's weird because I can reach the file by clicking the url from the 400 error that showing up in the developer tool window. I've tried to clear my cache and to browse in incognito mode...
Could it has something to do with my htaccess file ? I didn't made any change on it.

Comment: You're using the stock Craft `.htaccess` file, then? Can you edit the original question to include the AJAX code you're using as well as your `config/elementapi.php` file?

Comment: I was using POST not GET.
Just figured out by reading my question...
Thanks anyway

Comment: Ahh... nice catch.  Would you mind adding that as an official answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mistake in the ajax request. 
I was using POST instead of GET.

1) After installing the plugin :

Add **elementapi.php** to your `/craft/config/` directory

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'news.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
            'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("news/{$entry->id}.json")
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

2) **Enabling CSRF Protection**
add `'enableCsrfProtection' => true` to your `/craft/config/general.php` file.

3) getting entries with ajax :

**_layout.html**

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var data = {
            'CSRF': $('input[name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN"]').val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            'type': 'get',
            'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'cache': false,
            'data': data,
            'url': 'news.json',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'timeout': 50000
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (error) {
                // Total fail.
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
...
```